# Copy textarea text to clipboard html / javascript

Tags: javascript, html, copy, textarea, clipboard

hey, i know there's lots of tutorials out there but none seem to be working for me.

I have this :

```
<textarea name="forum_link" type="text" style="width:630px; height:90px;">
[URL=http://www.site.net/video/<?=$_GET['id']?>/<?=$_GET['tag']?>]<?=$video->title?>[/URL]

[URL=http://www.site.net/video/<?=$_GET['id']?>/<?=$_GET['tag']?>][IMG]<?=$video->thumbnailURL?>[/IMG][/URL]
</textarea>
```

Now all i want is a simple button, that when clicked copies the text in the textarea to the users clipboard.

Any help would be great :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly there's no all in one solution for this. Browsers other than IE doesnt allow copying to clipboard. I found I nice solution recently which uses Flash (for all browsers but IE) and JavaScript for IE to copy text to the clipboard. See [zeroclipboard](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/) for details.

Comment: This is now outdated, see MeKoo Solution's answer below for a more up to date answer.

Answer (score 13):

```
<textarea id="html" name="html">Some text</textarea>
<input type="button" value="Refresh" onclick="copy_to_clipboard('html');">

<script>
function copy_to_clipboard(id)
{
    document.getElementById(id).select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this page. It doesn't say anything about browser compatibility, but could be worth checking out! It gives a javascript copy to clipboard example, and the HTML associated with it.

http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial126_Clipboard-cut-copy-and-paste-with-JavaScript.html

Comment: The comments suggest this is IE only.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is purely on Javascript. i don't know about its compatibility with other browsers. For chrome its working,  I am adding the code snippet.

```js
//all text written(inside text area), is copied and shown inside the div with class "mas"
//you can't see it, as it is hidden(opacity is 0)

$('#content:not(.focus)').keyup(function(){     
        
        
    var value = $(this).val();
    var contentAttr = $(this).attr('name');
    
    $('.'+contentAttr+'').html(value.replace(/\r?\n/g,'<br/>'));
    
})

//below code can copy text inside a div. div id should be identical with button oclick id  

copyToClipboard = function (element) {
    var $temp = $("<input />");
    $("body").append($temp);
    $temp.val($(element).text()).select();

    var result = false;
    try {
        result = document.execCommand("copy");
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Copy error: " + err);
    }

    $temp.remove();
    return result;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="mas" rows="6" id="content"></textarea>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div id="p1" class="mas" style="top:0px;position:absolute;opacity:0;" ></div>

<button onclick="copyToClipboard('#p1')">Copy P1</button>
```

Please see this [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abhisheksen/t96qd3qx/1/) for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

## Modern Solution

`document.execCommand('copy')` is now [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand)

Instead, we now have the [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API)

You can use the `writeText()` property to accomplish this:

```js
$('button').on('click', () => {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText($('textarea').val()).then(
    () => {
      console.log('clipboard successfully set');
    },
    () => {
      console.error('clipboard write failed');
    }
  );
});
```

or just simply:

```js
$('button').on('click', () => {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText($('textarea').val());
});
```

**Bonus**: This works with disabled textareas and is cross-browser compatible

Answer (score 0):

Browser compatibility using any script is shoddy at best. JavaScript intentionally doesn't natively allow this level of functionality with the operating system. It is possible to create a signed script that you'll have better luck with, but... that's a lot more work and hardly worth it. Most people know how to copy and paste...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately javascript does not have a universal way. Currently, the use of flash & javascript most universal way.
Look on a [LMCButton](http://lettersmarket.com/lmcbutton.html) - a small animated flash button (4 kb) for "Copy to clipboard".

Example of using javascript:

Get html code of the button: **function lmc_get_button(cliptext, idLMC)**

Update text in the button: **function lmc_set_text(idLMC, text)**